# gitlab workflow for git fork/clone

Tags: git, gitlab

I forked a project from master. I cloned this fork to my local server.After few days I synced from master that merged the changes from it to the clone of my fork.Now I want to push the new changes that were merged to my clone into my fork master. I am not able to do this. why not? If I were to delete the clone from my local server and clone again from my fork, I want it to be up to date with the original master instead of me syncing again.

TIA!

Comment: Check out [syncing a fork](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/).

Comment: The steps listed in "syncing a fork" is exactly what am doing. Notice the teip at the end "Tip: Syncing your fork only updates your local copy of the repository. To update your fork on GitHub, you must push your changes.". I do a push to push changes from local copy to my fork on github. github doesn't push any change that I merged from upsteam/master to my fork in github.